# BitmapImage.EndInit() throwing 'System.NotSupportedException'

Tags: c#, memorystream, bitmapimage

Here's my code:
I fill the MemoryStream here, with this code.

```
private void treeView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var a = treeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;

            if (a.Header.ToString().EndsWith(".jpg"))
            {
                Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(a.Tag.ToString());

                try
                {
                    OriginalImage.Dispose();  
                }
                catch { };
                OriginalImage = new MemoryStream(); 

                temp.Save(OriginalImage, ImageFormat.Bmp);                    
                Uri path = new Uri(a.Tag.ToString());
                actualImage.Source = new BitmapImage(path);

            }
        }
        catch { };
    }
```

Right after that block, this was suppose to happen, but on the "bitmap.EndInit()" I get the exception'System.NotSupportedException'.

```
 var bitmap = new BitmapImage();                
 bitmap.BeginInit();
 bitmap.StreamSource = OriginalImage;
 bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
 bitmap.EndInit();
 bitmap.Freeze();    
 actualImage.Source = bitmap;
```

Anyone has any idea of what might be causing that? Those methods were suppose to load a image in a System.Windows.Controls.Image and the second block is to return the loaded image to it's default values, before editing the picture.

The NotSupportedException.StackTrace is:

```
"at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)\r\n   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)\r\n   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()\r\n   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()\r\n   at WpfApplication2.MainWindow.resetBtn_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\\Users\\Albert Sato Damas\\Desktop\\ImageEditing - Copy - Copy\\WpfApplication2\\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 270"
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception? so we can see what is unhappy...

Comment: @MarcGravell How can I check that? I have only worked with Exceptions a few times.

Comment: in the debugger, you should just be able to look at the exception detail and click on the `.StackTrace`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes setting stream position to 0 before setting StreamSource can solve this problem:

```
inputImageStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: This is important if you use the stream to create a bitmapimage twice.